# JavaFX BarChart doesn't update

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following Controller for my window:

```
package window;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;

public class StatisticsController {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barChartHistogram;

    private SortedMap<String, Integer> _points;

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    public void onLoad(SortedMap<String, Integer> points) {
        barChartHistogram = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        barChartHistogram.setCategoryGap(0);
        barChartHistogram.setBarGap(0);
        xAxis.setLabel("Numer indeksu");
        yAxis.setLabel("Ilość punktów");
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Histogram");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> p: points.entrySet()) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(p.getKey(), p.getValue()));
        }
        barChartHistogram.getData().addAll(series);
        _points = points;
    }

    @FXML
    private void buttonShowPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        xAxis.setLabel("Numer indeksu");
        yAxis.setLabel("Ilość punktów");
        barChartHistogram = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        barChartHistogram.setCategoryGap(0);
        barChartHistogram.setBarGap(0);
        barChartHistogram.setTitle("XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
        barChartHistogram.setMaxHeight(1000);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Histogram");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> p: _points.entrySet()) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(p.getKey(), p.getValue()));
        }
        barChartHistogram.getData().addAll(series);
    }
}
```

The `.fxml` file for this window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="window.StatisticsController">
   <children>
      <BarChart fx:id="barChartHistogram" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="500.0">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </BarChart>
      <Button fx:id="buttonShow" layoutY="337.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonShowPressed" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now the problem is when I press the button, nothing changes (`onLoad()` method is here for testing the `onLoad` C#-like behaviour). The bar chart stays the same without data, labels or title (I checked the data in the debugger, the `barCharHistogram` object has my data under its `data` property). Am I doing something stupidly wrong? How can I make it like redraw the barchart?

Comment: You create a new bar chart. Aren't you intending to update the existing bar chart? At any rate, if you really intend to create a new one, you need to add it to the scene somewhere.

Comment: Ah, your're right. But then, how can I add `xAxis` and `yAxis` to the chart?

Comment: As with the chart, you already define the axes in the FXML. Just inject them into the controller the same way you do with the chart, and don't create new axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already define everything you need in the FXML. You should not be creating a new chart, or new axes, in the controller.

Add `fx:id`s to the axes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="window.StatisticsController">
   <children>
      <BarChart fx:id="barChartHistogram" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="500.0">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis fx:d="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </BarChart>
      <Button fx:id="buttonShow" layoutY="337.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonShowPressed" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and then you can do

```
public class StatisticsController {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barChartHistogram;

    private SortedMap<String, Integer> _points;

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xAxis ;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis ;


    @FXML
    private void buttonShowPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        xAxis.setLabel("Numer indeksu");
        yAxis.setLabel("Ilość punktów");
        barChartHistogram.setCategoryGap(0);
        barChartHistogram.setBarGap(0);
        barChartHistogram.setTitle("XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
        barChartHistogram.setMaxHeight(1000);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Histogram");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> p: _points.entrySet()) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(p.getKey(), p.getValue()));
        }
        barChartHistogram.getData().addAll(series);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeez, you're totally right. It's sometimes hard coming from C# background. Accepting your answer right now. Thanks!

Comment: Btw its kinda strange, cuz I get the `yAxis` right, but the `xAxis` looks like this: https://imgur.com/f3kJIdR. Is there something wrong?

Comment: @Frynio The issue there is the positioning of the labels on the x-axis? That looks weird. It looks like a different issue though. I would suggest creating a complete standalone example that reproduces that and asking a new question.

Comment: I guess the problem is the data on xAxis would be 6 letters long, and maybe it doesn't display it well