# JavaFX BarChart xAxis labels bad positioning

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I have the following Controller for my window:

```
package window;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;

public class StatisticsController {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<?, ?> barChartHistogram;

    private SortedMap<String, Integer> _points;

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    public void onLoad(SortedMap<String, Integer> points) {
        xAxis.setLabel("Numer indeksu");
        yAxis.setLabel("Ilość punktów");
        //barChartHistogram.setBarGap(0);
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        int a = 10;
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Tom", 10));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Andrew", 7));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Patrick", 5));


        /*for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> p: points.entrySet()) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(Integer.toString(a), p.getValue()));
            a += 10;
        }*/
        barChartHistogram.getData().addAll(series1);
        _points = points;
    }

}
```

The `.fxml` file for this window:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="window.StatisticsController">
   <children>
      <BarChart fx:id="barChartHistogram" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="1500.0">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </BarChart>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Everything works perfectly except one thing:

[image]

As you can see the x axis label works fine, but the x axis labels (I mean like column names), which should be `Tom`, `Andrew` and `Patrick` are placed in exact same position (through this mess you can actually read `Patrick`) a the 0 position of x axis. Where is the problem? Should I make some changes to the UI or something?

Comment: I ran your code and didn't have a problem.

Comment: Okay. So where can it be? Can it be using Java 9, not 8?

Comment: I use `Java 8`.

Comment: Well, Java 8 doesn't help, checked it

Comment: Stumbled upon very similar issue. After lengthy debugging and trying several workarounds I was forced to admit that the issue is indeed unfixable and stems from bugs in histogram class. It is beyond me how could they miss something as obvious as this.

Comment: worksforme (java 9.0.1)

Comment: hmm ... just looked into your other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48994521/203657 and can reproduce the broken layout if I load the data series dynamically with the button ...

Comment: I have a bar chart flipped so the bars go left to right with the label turned 90 degrees - when there are only a couple of bars it doesn't respect the layout of the label. I think there are issues with how the axis labels are rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [bug with auto-range](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198830) of CategoryAxis if the data is set dynamically.

Below is a (non-fxml) example that demonstrates the issue with a crude hack-around: set the categories manually instead of let the chart/axis find them.

```
public class BarChartBug extends Application {

    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;
    private BarChart<String, Number> barChart;

    private Parent createContent() {
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        Button initData = new Button("init");
        initData.setOnAction(e -> {
            xAxis.setLabel("Numer indeksu");
            yAxis.setLabel("Ilo punktw");
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Tom", 10));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Andrew", 7));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Patrick", 5));

            // hack-around:
            // xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Tom", "Andrew", "Patrick"));
            barChart.getData().addAll(series1);

            initData.setDisable(true);

        });
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(barChart);
        pane.setBottom(initData);
        return pane;

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(BarChartBug.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: You're totally right, actually got that myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9):

I found another work around for this. Simply set `xAxis.setAnimated(false)`

Comment: this is the better workaround. Setting it manually is prone to errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug relevant animated property, you can:

- set `xAxis.setAnimated(false)`
  or
- set animated attribute false: `<CategoryAxis animated="false" side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is fun , but i was facing the same problem with java11 https://youtu.be/2ZKzWciKtIc?t=36 , after  my chart data was loaded the category labels never show. After few tries i decided to set the chart data in a timeline and after it finish set the category labels manually.

```
Duration duration = Duration.millis(300);
Platform.runLater(()->{
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(duration,event -> {
            barChart.getData().clear();
            barChart.getData().add(series1);
            barChart.getData().addAll(series2);
            //Clear all bofore to evitate Exceptions
            catAxis.getCategories().clear();                           
        })
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {
    //Set animated as false, so if true all labels will be one in top of the others 
    barChart.setAnimated(false);
    //The trick that worked forr me
    catAxis.getCategories().addAll(lists);
});
timeline.play();  });
```