# Categories labal in BarChart surpass one another in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, scenebuilder

I have a problem with the BarChart only at the first upload, the categories labels surpass one another. it looks like this:

[image: the problem:]

and from the second load, everything looks good:

[image]

the code:

```
@FXML
    private ComboBox<String> subDepList;

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> subDepChart;

    @FXML
    private Button showButton;

    @FXML
    private Label sdErrorMessage;


@FXML
    void setSubDepBarChart(Event event) {
        subDepChart.getData().clear();
        sdErrorMessage.setVisible(false);
        boolean flag = true;
        
        int sdId = -1;
        try {
            sdId = Integer.parseInt(subDepList.getValue());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            sdErrorMessage.setVisible(true);
            flag=false;
        }
        
        if (flag) {
            SubDepartment sd = Hospital.getInstance().getRealSubDepartment(sdId);
            //setting sub-department bar chart
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> set1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
            set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Patients", sd.getPatients().size()));
            set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Doctors", sd.getDoctors().size()));
            set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Nurses", sd.getNurses().size()));
            set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Reports", sd.getReports().size()));
            
            subDepChart.getData().addAll(set1);
        }
    }
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Try adding the categories to the `CategoryAxis#getCategories()` list as well.

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: there had been a bug that's fixed recently (afair, not entirely certain), so updating to a newer version of fx might help. Also this question has been asked here before, there might be answers with workarounds (again, afair :)

Comment: Duplicate: [JavaFX BarChart xAxis labels bad positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995257/javafx-barchart-xaxis-labels-bad-positioning)

Comment: was wrong: it's not fixed https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198830