# JavaFX LineChart: String values of a CategoryAxis are collapsed

Tags: javafx, linechart

I come with a question regarding a LineChart. I have a LineChart with xAxis as a CategoryAxes where I have dates and the yAxis as a NumberAxis where I have some numbers.
My problem is that on the xAxis, the values shown under the chart are overlapped and I cannot find the cause.

[image]

Here is my code where I setup the LineChart and display it:

```
private void createSecondLineChart(String gameName) {
    xAxis2 = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis2.setLabel("Dată");

    yAxis2.setLabel("Încercări");
    yAxis2.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis2.setLowerBound(0);
    yAxis2.setUpperBound(10);
    yAxis2.setTickUnit(2);

    lineChart2.setTitle("Statistică dată/încercări");

    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> chartData = DBUtils.getFirstGameDateStats(Stats.username,
                conn);
    lineChart2.setData(chartData);
    for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : chartData) {
        for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> entry : series.getData()) {
            String date = String.format("Data: %s\n", entry.getXValue());
            String tries = String.format("Incercari: %s\n", entry.getYValue().intValue());
            double dbAvgScore = DBUtils.getAverageScoreForUserInSpecificDate(Stats.username, entry.getXValue(),
                        conn);
            String avgScore = String.format("Punctaj mediu: %.2f", dbAvgScore);

            entry.getNode().setOnMouseEntered(event -> entry.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0084b8;"));
            entry.getNode().setOnMouseExited(event -> entry.getNode().setStyle(""));

            String tooltipText = date + tries + avgScore;
            Tooltip t = new Tooltip(tooltipText);
            t.setShowDelay(javafx.util.Duration.millis(0));
            Tooltip.install(entry.getNode(), t);
        }
    }
    lineChart2.setLegendVisible(false);
    lineChart2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Try `lineChart2.getXAxis().setAnimated(false);`. Or just `xAxis2.setAnimated(false);`

Comment: UPDATE: I've seen that after I press to populate again the LineChart, the labels are moved to their correct spot. Any idea how to make them go in their spot from the first time? Here is a gif of the behavior: https://imgur.com/a/8wZI63k

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. Setting `lineChart2.getXAxis().setAnimated(false);` worked. To avoid this behavior for other graph data sets in the future, I've set `lineChart2.setAnimated(false);`.

Comment: it's a bug - and this question a duplicate  [JavaFX BarChart xAxis labels bad positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995257/javafx-barchart-xaxis-labels-bad-positioning)